# HTML IMG override all height limitations

Tags: html

Need to setup an HTML TABLE that contains one or more HTML IMG and do not want HTML IMG to trigger a vertical scroll bar. I know that HTML IMG can be set with explicit pixel dimension limits, and that works just fine in limiting vertical size. But I want the HTML TABLE to use say 90% of the screen height, and the HTML IMG inside the HTML TABLE to use say 90% of the HTML TABLE. I've tried a half dozen different ways of trying to implement this, none of which have any effect. In all cases, an image that exceeds the screen height enlarges the HTML TABLE and triggers a vertical scroll bar. Here is the code I've most recently tried, and pardon the many pathetic redundant shots at limiting the vertical:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  html, body {
    height:100%;
  }
  #images {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
  }
  #images img {
    width:100%;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<caption align="bottom">this photo caption</caption>
<tr>
<td height="90%"><img src="Images/plate70.jpg"/></td>
</tr>
</table>    
<p align="left">
<a href="chap1.xhtml#P70"><button>Text</button></a>
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.resizeTo(500,200);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `table-layout: fixed` on the table element. Otherwise `width` and `height` are treated as `min-width` and `min-height`.

Comment: You mean like this? I'm afraid it had no effect. The selected image still extends beyond the physical screen size and triggers a scroll bar. <style>...table { table-layout:fixed; } </style>. Also put explicit pixel height in table CSS but no help.

Comment: Well, you define styles for an element with the id `images`, but there is no element with that ID..

Comment: Added id="images" to both img declarations and reduced #images height to 80% but still get vertical scroll bar.

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same ID. Use a class.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. Did <style type="text/css">img.a{height:50%;}</style> and then <img class="a" src="image1.jpg" width="100%"/> and <img class="a" src="image2.jpg" width="100%"/> but image1.jpg still pushes the vertical far enough to trigger a scroll bar.

Comment: Okay... try removing the `width="100%"` things, because if you're defining a width they should be in CSS and not attributes that have been deprecated since HTML4 ;)

Comment: Ouch! Removing the width=100% for both IMGs resulted in blowing out the horizontal limits of the table and triggering a horizontal scroll bar. It seems that HTML TABLE is willing to resize and limit horizontally but not vertically. Ideally, the table cells should accept fixed dimensions, e.g., 50% of screen width each, and perhaps 80% of screen height each, leaving vertical space for caption and other effects. But the HTML IMGs consistently blow out the cell heights.

Comment: I don't know what it is you're doing exactly, but I've never had problems like this. For example, one of my pages has a table with images in the cells, each image has a width of 100% and each cell has a width of 20% (there are five of them, so that totals 100%) and finally the table has 100% width. The result is images that resize when you change the window size, and works perfectly fine.

Comment: I now have
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
  height:100%;
}
table {
  height:70%;
}
img.a {
  width:100%;
  height:50%;
}
</style>
and
<tr>
<td width="50%"><img class="a" src="Images/plate94.jpg"/></td>
<td width="50%"><img class="a" src="ThenAndNow/Stavelot_Tiger_North_2011.jpg"/></td>
</tr>

Comment: See original post for what I'm trying to accomplish. One row, two cells, 50/50 width of full screen for the two cells, with cell height roughly 80% of full screen to leave room for caption and some buttons. The code I presently have resizes both images, dissimilar raw dimensions, to the 50/50 horizontal split. But after resizing horizontally to the 50/50 horizontal split, the resultant vertical size of one of the images is larger than the physical screen and triggers a vertical scroll bar. Images are good, not distorted. But I need to lose the vertical scroll bar.

Comment: If I create separate classes for each image, and set a width of 70% for the first image, the one that is triggering the vertical scroll bar, and a width of 100% for the second image, the results are good, no vertical scroll bar, because the first image now has horizontal white space. But there's no way to statically know how to vary the two width percentages.